# I want to fill empty fields in a column with data from the previous month

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[Table model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT5qZ.png)
I have a table called "MYSTERY_SHOPPER" that is loaded with monthly data. As you can see in the image, February was loaded but has no values in the "Lista de Precio" column, so I need the value of last month to be loaded, comparing if the model loaded in the "Modelo" column is the same as the last month.

```
Dim rs As Recordset

    Dim datefield As String
    Dim modelfield As String
    Dim pricefield As String

    Dim modeldict As Object

    Set modeldict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MYSTERY_SHOPPER")

    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            datefield = ![Fecha]
            modelfield = ![Modelo]
            If Not IsNull(![Precio de Lista]) Then
                pricefield = ![Precio de Lista]
                If Not modeldict.Exists(modelfield) Then
                    modeldict.Add modelfield, datefield & "|" & pricefield
                Else
                    If Split(modeldict(modelfield), "|")(0) < datefield Then
                        modeldict(modelfield) = datefield & "|" & pricefield
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                .Edit
                ![Precio de Lista] = Split(modeldict(modelfield), "|")(1)
                .Update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
```

I thought of something like that but it doesn't work, it doesn't do anything.

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could populate the empty prices using an `update` query, such as the following:

```sql
update mystery_shopper m
set 
    m.[precio de lista] =
    dlookup
    (
        "[precio de lista]",
        "mystery_shopper",
        "modelo = '" & m.modelo & "' and fecha = " & 
        format
        (
            nz
            (
                dmax
                (
                    "fecha",
                    "mystery_shopper",
                    "modelo = '" & m.modelo & "' and fecha < " & 
                    format(m.fecha,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
                )
                ,#1901-01-01#
            )
            ,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"
        )
    )
where
    m.[precio de lista] is null or m.[precio de lista] = 0
```

I've resorted to using the domain aggregate functions `dlookup` and `dmax` as I believe using correlated subqueries to obtain the most recent price will cause the query to become not updateable, though there may be a better way to tackle this.

---

Alternatively, you could solve this in 3 steps:

1. Execute a query to create a temporary table containing the most recent price for each `modelo`:

   ```sql
   select m.modelo,
       (
           select top 1 n.[precio de lista]
           from mystery_shopper n
           where n.modelo = m.modelo and n.fecha < m.fecha
           order by n.fecha desc
       ) as precio
   into temp_table
   from
       mystery_shopper m
   where
       m.[precio de lista] is null or
       m.[precio de lista] = 0
   ```
2. Use an `update` query to update the prices in the `mystery_shopper` table, sourcing data from the temporary table:

   ```sql
   update mystery_shopper m inner join temp_table t on m.modelo = t.modelo
   set m.[precio de lista] = t.precio
   where 
       (m.[precio de lista] is null or m.[precio de lista] = 0) and
       t.precio is not null and
       t.precio <> 0
   ```
3. Delete the temporary table:

   ```sql
   drop table temp_table
   ```

Comment: Friend, the first solution works perfect, however, I was wondering if I could include it as an Sql statement within a button, not as a query button, but within a button that already has more sql sentences. 

Something like SqlOrder = "update mystery_shopper ....". Can u help me please.

Comment: You're welcome. The JET database engine used by MS Access can only execute one SQL statement at a time; as such, you will need to execute your SQL statements consecutively, using either `DoCmd.RunSQL` or `CurrentDb.Execute` to execute each statement; or save each query and construct a macro to execute the queries consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is there is a value in `![Precio de Lista]` the value is just 0. To get it to populate that you will need to check for 0 in addition to null.

Change this line:

```
If Not IsNull(![Precio de Lista]) Then
```

To:

```
If Not (IsNull(![Precio de Lista]) or ![Precio de Lista] = 0) Then
```

That should fix the issue

Comment: Still doing nothing :(

Comment: Nothing, the values not change, still like "0"